# hot to fix logstash is not connected to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I installed ElasticSearch, Kibana, and Logstash on the official website.

Each version is 8.8.1.

No other settings are not modified at all, and both `kibana` and `elasticsearch` have been executed.

However, `logstash` generates errors and does not run.

Below is an error and a logstash setting file.

```js
[2023-06-16T17:55:34,000][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2023-06-16T17:55:34,042][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2023-06-16T17:55:34,062][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:790) ~[jruby.jar:?]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:753) ~[jruby.jar:?]
    at Users.kun.Downloads.ElasticSearch.logstash_minus_8_dot_8_dot_1.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/Users/kun/Downloads/ElasticSearch/logstash-8.8.1/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:91) ~[?:?]
```

```js
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "./mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db" 
        jdbc_user => "root" 
        jdbc_password =>"root"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "SELECT id, name, createdTime at FROM user limit 500"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "music_user"
        document_id =>"%{id}"

    } stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

I think it may be a `SSL` problem.

If the `SSL` of `Elasticsearch` was released, `Kibana` did not run, but the `logstash` was executed.

But I think you should not release `SSL`.

When I set up SSL, I can't access it via HTTP, but I'm running it locally, so I don't have an HTTPS address.

How can I solve this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code worked like this

```js
hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
user => "xxxx"
password => "xxxx"
ssl_certificate_verification => false
```